# How to get the output columns using a sql query

Tags: sql, postgresql

My table

```
id           updateddate        updatedbyuser   department
-------------------------------------------------------
40715449759  12/7/2018 12:24            1260    IB
40715449759  12/8/2018 10:40            1203    ESCALATION
40715449759  12/8/2018 10:40            task
40715449759  12/9/2018 9:58           client
40715449759  12/9/2018 12:09       300050282    ESCALATION
42058447691  12/23/2018 16:44           1712    TASK
42058447691  12/26/2018 19:33           4700    ESCALATION
42058447691  12/27/2018 17:26           7357    ESCALATION
```

Output

```
id            first_action_date
--------------------------------
40715449759   12/8/2018 10:40
42058447691   12/26/2018 19:33
```

I'm trying to extract id and first_action_time from mytable where the first instance of updateddate is first_action_date where the department is ESCALATION for a unique id

Answer (score 1):

Just use an aggregation with `min` as

```
select id, 
       min(first_action_date) 
       as first_action_date
  from mytable
 where department = 'ESCALATION'
 group by id
```

Answer (score 1):

Postgres has a feature called `distinct on`, which can be used in this case:

```
select distinct on (id) id, first_action_date
from t
where department = 'ESCALATION'
order by id, first_action_date asc;
```

Although your particular query can be handled directly by `group by`, this is handy if you want other columns, such as the user.  To get the entire row:

```
select distinct on (id) t.*
from t
where department = 'ESCALATION'
order by id, first_action_date asc;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select id, updateddate as first_action_date from table where department= 'ESCALATION' order by id
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, it is better to explain how to solve the problem and provide the code as an example or reference. Code-only answers can be confusing and lack context.